# Centering Slide Content with Reusable and Scoped Styles in Marp

Tags: html, css, markdown, presentation, marp

How can I center the slide content with reusable and scoped to the specific slide without repeating myself in [Marp](https://marp.app/)?

I had some success using something like this, but it only works if I copy and paste it on all the other slides:

```
---

<style scoped>
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

</style>

# Questions

---
```

I tried to apply it with @apply and using class, but with no success.

Comment: https://marpit.marp.app/theme-css

Comment: Can you reference to the place where I can modify specific slide layout without repeating `style scoped`